# Android recording call as text

Tags: java, android

I am making an app for personal use and i want to convert speech to text when i accept the phone call.
However, when i run it on my real device it says the app has stopped working. The emulator in android studio won't use the microphone. I am just a beginner so could you explain why this isn't working? 
I have placed the permission in manifest and everything.  Thank you

```
public class ReceiveCall extends BroadcastReceiver {




    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {


        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)){
            SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);

            Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

            mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

            mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onEndOfSpeech() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int error) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResults(Bundle results) {
                    ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                    if(matches!= null){
                        Toast.makeText(context,""+matches.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

                }
            });


            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);


        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"NOT IN PHONE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.royyo.speechtotext.ReceiveCall: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services
        at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.bindService(ContextImpl.java:137)
        at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(SpeechRecognizer.java:287)
        at com.example.royyo.speechtotext.ReceiveCall.onReceive(ReceiveCall.java:86)
```

Comment: Please post crash logs from log-cat, your question is not giving much idea about why you are facing such problem.

Comment: I have posted the log-cat and i was looking at the error and did some googling. I am not sure if i got it correctly but BroadcastReceiver has to be light and can't process any service which SpeechRecognizer is. is this correct?  if it is how would i approach this problem?